# Add Time to NSDate

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have two UIDatePicker in a view. One for getting Date and Another for the Time. I am getting the Time properly. Now I need to Append Time with the Date for setting firedate of Local Notification. On appending both, I am getting null in NSDate

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM,dd YYYY HH:mm a"];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",txtDate.text,txttime.text]];
localNotif.fireDate = tempDate;
```

While txtDate.text is Aug,06 2012 and txtTime.text is 7:04 pm.
I am getting tempDate as null. I have tried various date format for this. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` doesnt match

> Aug,06 2012 7:04 pm

it should be `MMM,dd YYYY HH:mm a`

also since you're pm is in lower case, you may need to set the `AMSymbol` and `PMSymbol` properties of the date formatter

Comment: Thanks for replay, I have changed the format that you have suggest. Still no impact.

Comment: @Arvind And here's the link to help you learn more about the time literals used at ios/macos: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @Arvind I've updated the dateformat based on the above link, can you try that?

Answer (score 1):

Check with this If helpful.

```
MMM,dd yyyy HH:mm
```

Comment: See I have edited and remove 'a' format. It giving date but month is not in word.